# How to check if one grid ref is within 1 km of another grid ref

Tags: distance, excel

How to check if one grid ref is within 1 km of another grid ref

Data is in northings/eastings.

Where there is more than one grid ref within 1km, I need the nearest. Granted once we have the distances I hope that will be trivial.

I need to use Excel.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  Please [edit] your question to include some more information about your data, including a sample of your data.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=distance+between+two+points

Answer (score 1):

Since OSGB is a flat coordinate system in metres the distance is the square root of delta X squared plus delta y squared. Where delta x is the difference between the two x values and delta y is the difference between the two y values.

Comment: thanks, solution created. I'd post it here but can't see how. I spent hours searching google and here and would like to offer it for future searchers, though ... judging by the reaction to my request for help that's not a good idea?

Comment: try taking http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour  to find out how we roll here

Comment: thank you - 1.6 billion calculations now successfully performed.